# регулярное выражение, которое будет соответствовать следующей строке в многострочном тексте

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Написать регулярное выражение, которое будет соответствовать следующей строке в многострочном тексте:

`ХХ-00-111`

где:

- `ХХ` - любые 2 заглавные буквы кириллицы;
- `00` - 4 либо 5 цифр;
- `111` - одна и более цифр.

Comment: Несмотря на то, что вам, скорее всего, помогут с ответом,
все же [ознакомьтесь с теорией](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Если что-то будет не понятно, задавайте вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша строка:

```
^[А-Я]{2}-[0-9]{4,5}-[0-9]+$
```

Где:

- `^` - начало строки
- `[А-Я]` - выбор символов в диапазоне от `A` до `Я` в [ASCII таблице](http://ascii-table.com/img/cp1251.gif)
- `{2}` - кол-во выбираемых символов (`==2`)
- `-` - символ "-"
- `[0-9]` - выбор символов в диапазоне от `0` до `9`
- `{4,5}` - кол-во выбираемых символов (`>=4 && <=5`)
- `[0-9]`...
- `+` - кол-во выбираемых символов `>=1` (соответсвует `{1,}`)
- `$` - конец строки

Также вам нужно указать в опциях, что вы хотите использовать `Multiline`:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"^[А-Я]{2}-[0-9]{4,5}-[0-9]+$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

[Тестить](https://dotnetfiddle.net/taEsH4), [Теория](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.4.php).